# function taking variadic number of initializer_lists with different types

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11, clang

**NOTE:** this question was caused by a bug in clang

---

In attemping to write a function taking an arbitrary number of `intitializer_list`s whose types need not match, I've stumbled upon a strange error:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void function(std::initializer_list<Ts> &&  ...args){

}

int main() {
    function({1,2,3}, {'h', 'w'}, {"hello", "aloha"});
    return 0;
}
```

The string literals cause a problem under clang but not under gcc with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra` not warning about any extensions.

clang produces the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'function'
    function({1,2,3}, {'h', 'w'}, {"hello", "aloha"});
    ^~~~~~~~
note: candidate function [with Ts = <int, char, char const[6]>] not
      viable: no known conversion from 'const char [6]' to 'char const[6]' for
      3rd argument
void function(std::initializer_list<Ts> &&  ...args){
     ^
```

So a few questions:
Is clang wrong for rejecting this or is gcc using an extension to deduce an initializer_list of arrays?  Or is it deeper where gcc is just passing bad code?

Is this is the equivalent of passing an `initializer_list` of `initializer_list`s which is of course not allowed?

What is the difference between `const char[6]` and `char const[6]`?

Details:

clang version 3.4 (http://llvm.org/git/clang.git 9a65f4251fe5548e0b4478d584796ca84a6f5ebc) (http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git 4f67afc3d67d9a68f1b37767c9c2966a775186bd)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2

Debian 7

Comment: What exact versions of GCC and of CLANG are you using? On which operating system? I tend to think that GCC is right... but I am not sure...

Comment: Works in IDEONE: http://ideone.com/C3UGId I guess they use g++ 4.8

Comment: VC2013 also compiles, so I suspect that this is a bug in clang...

Comment: gcc is not deducing an `initializer_list` of arrays, it's deducing `std::initializer_list<const char*>`. See the compiler warnings [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2de790d6fd79b8c) `In instantiation of ‘void function(std::initializer_list<Ts>&& ...) [with Ts = {int, char, const char*}]’`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in clang: it fails to perform the required array-to-pointer decay when deducing `{"hello", "aloha"}` against `std::initializer_list<Ts>`, but only when `Ts` is a parameter pack.

This program [compiles fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75f4b2f85c26ed88):

```
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T>
void function(std::initializer_list<T> il) {
}

int main() {
    function({"hello", "aloha", "foobarbaz"});
}
```

but this program [triggers the bug](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad802152489dcb12):

```
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename... T>
void function(std::initializer_list<T>... il) {
}

int main() {
    function({"hello", "aloha", "foobarbaz"});
}
```

Edit: Could not find this bug in [the LLVM bugzilla tracker](http://llvm.org/bugs), submitted as [bug# 18047](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18047).